# PFSignUpViewController, AutoFill -- Cannot show Automatic Strong Passwords

Tags: ios, parse-server, pfuser

I am getting an error in an iOS app, that I do not recall having seen before.
Here it is:

```
..[1234:1015678] [AutoFill] Cannot show Automatic Strong Passwords
for app bundleID: mydomain.myapp due to error: Cannot save passwords for this app.
Make sure you have set up Associated Domains for your app
and AutoFill Passwords is enabled in Settings
```

I am using iOS 12.2 and Xcode 10.2. And after searching the net, I suspect this is somewhat due to a new feature of iOS. But anyway I do not understand why the problem has to do with AutoFill Passwords when I am filling the password by hand.

It happens with `PFSignUpViewController` and this is where I hit this issue.

When a new user wants to sign up,  he/she must fill 3 fields: username, password and email. One can fill up the username and email with no trouble.
But when touching the password field, the above message appears.

In case the username and email field are filled up first and the password is filled up last, then all happens normally and we could "pretend we have not seen the message" (though it appears); the sign up happens as it should.

On the other hand in case the password is filled before the rest is completed, the program stops when trying to go and edit one of the two other fields.

Any tip or advice by someone who has seen the issue before would be very welcome.

Comment: You can ignore this message. It is simply telling you that you haven't set up a link for password storage/sharing between your app and your web site

Comment: OK. I like your answer, but I am still in trouble (as I mentioned) when the user fills the password first and then the email (for example). How can I get the problem solved?

Comment: What happens when "the program stops"? Do you get an error message? A crash?

Comment: OK. I just went back to check the problem again. Your are probably right, because the problem left seems unrelated to this. Thanks.